# Elasticsearch. How to pick 4 matches from each Title?

Tags: elasticsearch

I wish to pick 4 different recipes from my doc by title.

I tried something like this:

```
        body: {
      '_source': {
        'includes': 4,
      },
      'size': 4,
      'query': {
        bool: {
          should: [
            {match: {Title: {query: 'Eggs', operator: 'OR'}}},
            {match: {Title: {query: 'Apple', operator: 'OR'}}},
            {match: {Title: {query: 'Onion', operator: 'OR'}}},
            {match: {Title: {query: 'spaghetti', operator: 'OR'}}},
          ],
        },
      },
    }
```

But without success. It finds only spaghetti recipe but if Im looking for onion recipes I can find them in another query so my merged query makes nosense :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to fetch "n" documents per clause in query part. You need to use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation to achieve it.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "Title": {
              "query": "Eggs",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Title": {
              "query": "Apple",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Title": {
              "query": "Onion",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "Title": {
              "query": "spaghetti",
              "operator": "OR"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "recipies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Title.keyword",
        "size": 10000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 4
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Terms aggregation will work like group by and top_hits will return top "4" documents for each group.